# How to reload/refresh a single row in a grid after a successfull update in Extjs?

Tags: datagrid, extjs4, store

I have tried to refresh or reload an updated row in a data grid, because I don't want to refresh the whole grid if, there is only 1 or 2 rows updated.

My try:

```
...
store.sync({
    success : function(rec, op, success) {
        ....
        var store = Ext.getStore('TheStore');
        for (var i = 0; i < rec.operations.length; i++) {
             //You can only update rows in my grid. 
             //No other options avaialable!
             var recdId = store.indexOf(rec.operations[0].records[i]);
             grid.getView().refreshNode(recdId);  
        }
        ....
}),
...
```

With that code the grid isn't refreshing the updated rows at all. It looks like nothing happens but I don't know why?! 
Is someone facing the same problem or maybe have a solution?
Would be nice, if someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are syncing the grid store and you don't want to refresh the entire view?

Comment: That is right. I just want to refresh the updated records and not the entire grid.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If I understand correctly, the output should be the same either way, no?

Comment: If I change the data in the grid and click on the safe button. The record is updated correctly but the record in the grid is still the 'old' one. You don't see the changes, if you don't reload the store. I want that the changed data appear directly after the sync procedure.

Comment: If I do that `Ext.getStore("TheStore").reload()` it takes too much time, because the whole table with the whole data will be reloaded. I just want to reload the updated data, so I save a lot of time and performance.

Comment: I'm guessing the record you are updating uses a different store than the one in grid. If you use the same store for grid as for the updated record, the grid view will show the new data even before the sync happens.

Comment: No, I am using only one store for this grid and after I update the records the new records aren't displayed. The grid view looks like before the update, only if I refresh it the actual and updated view shows up.

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/) reproducing your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125669/discussion-between-f4k3d-and-marthym).